# Susy grid issues: TypeError: No implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby, sass, susy-sass

I'm new to sass and I'm trying to move away from bootstrap in favour of a more tailored and less chubby framework. I'd really like to create nice grid layout using susy but I've came across a problem when trying to compile the scss files into css.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
error sass/style.scss (/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:19:in `extname': no implicit conversion of nil into String)
```

I looked at the file in question and it seems to be referencing a file type and it's ext;

```
@file_type = File.extname(@file)[1..-1].downcase
```

Here's the backtrace;

```
    /*

TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Backtrace:
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:19:in `extname'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:19:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:54:in `new'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:54:in `image_dimensions'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/lib/compass/core/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb:12:in `image_height'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:394:in `visit_prop'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `map'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `block in visit_rule'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:428:in `visit_rule'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `map'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `block in visit_rule'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:428:in `visit_rule'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:17:in `block in render'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:29:in `with_import_scope'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:16:in `render'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:492:in `update_stylesheet'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in `block in update_stylesheets'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:470:in `on_file_changed'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:328:in `block in watch'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:252:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:252:in `on_change'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/listener.rb:290:in `block in initialize_adapter'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:254:in `call'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:254:in `report_changes'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:323:in `poll_changed_directories'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/vendor/listen/lib/listen/adapter.rb:299:in `block in start_poller'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String"; }
```

SCSS File

```
   @import "partials/normalize";
@import "partials/variables";
@import "partials/layout";
@import "partials/mixins";
@import "breakpoint";
@import "partials/grids";

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: $blue;
  color: $white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: $white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  ul, li {
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
    background: $gray;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $white;
    &:hover {
      color: $yellow;
    }
  }
}

.first-row {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first-row .first{
  background: $yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

.first-row .second{
  height: 100%;
}

.first-row .second div{
  background: $orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.pic-gallery {
  div {
    background: $violet;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

.content-bar {
  div {
    background: $green;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: $blue;
  color: $white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

// Grid Stuff

header {
  // Span the entire area available and eliminates floating elements
  @include full;

  // Have the logo take up 1.35 columns
  // You can add wide or wider to take 1 or 2 gutters in space
  // span(wide 1.35)
  .logo {
    @include span(1.35);
    // Sass helpers for getting image size
    height: image-height("./images/nttlogo.png");
    width: image-width("./images/nttlogo.png");
  }

  // Start at the last 2 column point
  h1 {
    @include span(last 2);

    @include breakpoint((max-width 50em)){
      @include span(last 4);
    }
  }
}

.nav {
  @include full;
}

.wrapper {
  // Return the container that uses the layouts we defined
  // You could pass in a size container(800px)
  @include container;
}

// Have each nav li item take up 3 columns of the layout with
// gutters inside
.nav-item {
  @include span(3 of $nav_susy_layout);

  // You can add 1 column of margin:
  // margin-bottom: span(1);
}

.first-row {
  // No floating elements on the left or right
  clear: both;
  .first {
    @include span(first 4);
  }
  .second {

    // Place in last 8 spaces
    @include span(last 8);
    div:nth-child(1) {

      // Take up to columns starting at 1st of 8
      @include span(2 at 1 of 8);
    }
    div:nth-child(2) {
      @include span(2 at 3 of 8);
    }
    div:nth-child(3) {
      @include span(2 at 5 of 8);
    }
    div:nth-child(4) {
      @include span(2 at 7 of 8);

      // Break element to the next row
      // @include break();
    }
    div:nth-child(5) {
      @include span(last 2 of 8);
    }

  }
}

.pic-gallery {
  @include clearfix;

  // Define the padding by passing the number of columns
  padding: gutter(12);

  // Add padding on sides
  padding: 0 10px;
  div {

    // Take up 2 of every 12 for all 6 pics
    @include gallery(2 of 12);
  }

  div:nth-child(5) {

      // Make the element take up the last position
      @include last();
  }

  div:nth-child(1) {

      // Make the element take up the last position
      // Move over 1 column @include pre(1);
      // Move to the left 1 column with pull(1);
      // Move content 1 column @include prefix(1);
      // Move content left 1 column @include suffix(1);
  }

}

.content-bar {
  // Add padding on sides
  padding: 0 10px;

  // Return the size of a gutter
  margin-top: gutter();

  div:nth-child(1){
    @include span(6 of 12);

    // You can add a specifically sized gutter before, after,
    // inside, or split
    @include gutters(3em inside);

    @include breakpoint((max-width 40em)){
      @include span(12 of 12);
    }
  }
  div:nth-child(2){
    @include span(last 6 of 12);

    @include breakpoint((max-width 40em)){
      @include span(12 of 12);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Some more code pls, like this scss file. Right now its seems that `@file` is `nil`, but why would it be so, I can't tell.

Comment: added as requested, any help would be great even if it's just some trouble shoot tips, i'm a little lost and following tutorials for the moment

Comment: Looks like Compass is can't find this file or that path it looks in is non-existant. Instead of `height: image-height("./images/nttlogo.png");
    width: image-width("./images/nttlogo.png");`
please try `height: image-height("nttlogo.png");
    width: image-width("nttlogo.png");`, assuming that nttlogo.png is in your images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yep that was it, I feel a little stupid, the file wasn't in the directory. Not quite as simple as spotting a dead link in the console as you would with standard CSS.  Ah well, we live and learn. Thanks for the help, this solved the issue.